# Eclipse - unable to install breakpoint - Don't tell me again setting

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

I got a message like this one here and (since I was in a hurry)
I clicked by mistake "Don't tell me again".

How do I make Eclipse tell me again (about such issues) ? :)

Comment: Hmm, switch to intellij? ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat LOL, OP try this: https://mcuoneclipse.com/2013/04/14/show-it-again-how-to-re-enable-hidden-dialogs-in-eclipse/

Comment: @prsvr That sounds like a better answer to the question. Although I am still convinced that IntelliJ is the better answer to eclipse, in general.

Comment: @GhostCat http://prntscr.com/ndng0t, I believe you :D

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Window > Preferences - > Java`. There you will an option under "Java dialogs" to clear the setting.

[image]